# How to generate Java files from WSDL and publish them?

Tags: sbt

I'm trying to create a plugin for sbt 0.12.1 that will generate java files from WSDL, compile them, and then publish the jar.

My project layout is like:

```
./build.sbt
./project/build.sbt
./project/WsdlBuild.scala
./src/main/wsdl/...many wsdl files...
```

I'm using axis to generate the java files, and `build.sbt` looks like:

```
name := "zxtm-api"

organization := "com.giltgroupe.zeus"

unmanagedBase <<= baseDirectory { base => base / "wsdl-lib" }

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "axis"              % "axis-wsdl4j"       % "1.2.1",
  "commons-logging"   % "commons-logging"   % "1.0.4",
  "commons-discovery" % "commons-discovery" % "0.2",
  "log4j"             % "log4j"             % "1.2.8",
  "org.apache.axis"   % "axis"              % "1.4",
  "org.apache.axis"   % "axis-ant"          % "1.4",
  "org.apache.axis"   % "axis-jaxrpc"       % "1.4",
  "org.apache.axis"   % "axis-saaj"         % "1.4"
)

gilt.zxtm.WsdlBuild.wsdlSettings
```

(There was one jar we couldn't find in any maven repo that's in `wsdl-lib`)

`project/build.sbt` is very similar:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "axis"              % "axis-wsdl4j"       % "1.2.1",
  "commons-logging"   % "commons-logging"   % "1.0.4",
  "commons-discovery" % "commons-discovery" % "0.2",
  "log4j"             % "log4j"             % "1.2.8",
  "org.apache.axis"   % "axis"              % "1.4",
  "org.apache.axis"   % "axis-ant"          % "1.4",
  "org.apache.axis"   % "axis-jaxrpc"       % "1.4",
  "org.apache.axis"   % "axis-saaj"         % "1.4"
)

unmanagedBase <<= baseDirectory { base => base / "wsdl-lib" }
```

So I wrote the code in `WsdlBuild.scala` to generate the java files, and ended up with something like:

```
object WsdlBuild extends Plugin {

  lazy val wsdlSourceDir = SettingKey[File]("wsdl-source-dir")
  lazy val wsdlToJava = TaskKey[Unit]("wsdl-to-java")
  lazy val managedSrcDir = file("target/src_managed/wsdl")

  val wsdlSettings = inConfig(Compile)(Seq(
    compile <<= compile dependsOn wsdlToJava,
    javaSource := managedSrcDir,
    managedSourceDirectories := Seq(managedSrcDir)
  )) ++ Seq(
    wsdlToJava <<= (wsdlSourceDir, managedSourceDirectories in Compile, state) map {
      (wsdlDir, managedDirs, s) =>
      // by convention use the first one. Not obvious why there is
      // ever more than one
        createJavaFromWsdl(wsdlDir, managedDirs.head, s.log)
    },
    wsdlSourceDir := file("src/main/wsdl")
  )

  def createJavaFromWsdl(wsdlDir: File, outputDir: File, log: Logger): File = { ... }
```

So this sort of works.  If I run `compile`, it generates the wsdl correctly. But if I `publish-local`, it doesn't compile.  So in order to `publish` or `publish-local`, and I have to manually `compile` first.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generating sources and resources is described [in this howto of the sbt docs](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Howto-Generating-Files.html).

In your case, `wsdlSettings` might look like:

```
  val wsdlSettings = inConfig(Compile)(Seq(
    sourceGenerators <+= wsdlToJava,
    wsdlSourceDir <<= baseDirectory(_ / "src/main/wsdl"),
    wsdlToJava <<= (wsdlSourceDir, sourceManaged, streams) map {
      (wsdlDir, managedDir, s) =>
        createJavaFromWsdl(wsdlDir, managedDir, s.log)
    },
  )
```

Some changes unrelated to your question:

- Get the logger from `streams`.  This sends output to a task-specific logger so that you can retrieve it individually.  See [this howto](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Howto-Logging.html) for more information on this.
- Always use absolute paths, often by basing a file on `baseDirectory`.  See [Use absolute paths](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Best-Practices.html#Use+absolute+paths).

Answer (score 0):

The question is quite old, although the problem might be still relevant to someone.

In my case, I approached a very similar problem by having an `sh` script that does all the dirty work of WSDL generation with `wsimport` (comes with Java out of the box). A dedicated `sbt` subproject wraps it as a task and executes on compilation. Such subproject can be easily inserted into any other, bigger `sbt` setup where you can just add a dependency on it.

Enough talking, here's a template on GitHub that demonstrates exactly that: https://github.com/sainnr/sbt-scala-wsdl-template. Hope it saves someone a good couple of hours messing around with WSDL and build tools. Feel free to fork or improve it if you find it any helpful!

Comment: Here's a post with a detailed description if anyone's interested: https://fullstackme.co.uk/dev/automate-soap-client-auto-generation-routines-with-wsdl-import-for-sbt-and-scala